# google cloud messaging batchImport successfully maps APNS tokens to GCM tokens but messages never get delivered

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I've followed the steps at the GCM docs [here](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#example_post_request_2) to do a batchImport of an APNS token and successfully receive a GCM token. However, when I post to https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send the request goes through with a message_id returned the phone never receives the notification.

Result from the batchImport endpoint:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "registration_token": "XXXX",
      "apns_token": "XXXX",
      "status": "OK"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a sample payload:

```
{
 "registration_ids":["XXXX"], 
 "notification": {"body": "Check this out!": "My app"},
 "priority": "high",
 "time_to_live": 28800,
 "content_available": true,
 "data": {...}
}
```

If the APNS token is mapped to GCM from the iOS app, then I can successfully send the same payload to the device using that GCM token. Any ideas why?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690850/google-cloud-messaging-showing-success-message-but-not-sending-ios

Comment: Looks like I got both the priority and content available set which makes this a bit puzzling.

Comment: @user5831382 I have the same issue, did you solve this?